# ModelAndViewDefiningException при вызове рест-методов?

Tags: java, spring, websphere

Приложение на spring 4.3.13.RELEASE версии и все модули, например mvc или web используют внутри себя servlet 3.0.1

Приложение задеплоено на websphere 8.5.5.13, на котором встроенный jar servlet 3.0

Работает все ок, но после перезагрузки приложения, при попытке повызывать ресты, получаю

Error 500: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndViewDefiningException

pom.xml файл выглядит так

...
    war

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.3.13.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <javax.servlet>3.0.1</javax.servlet>
    <hb.enity.manager>4.2.21.Final</hb.enity.manager>
    <spring.test>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.test>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>SBRiskDataSvcs</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test</testSourceDirectory>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!--SPRING-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- SERVLET-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.servlet}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--JACKSON AND XML-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--DATABASE-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.odb</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--APACHE-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--TEST-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--LOG4J-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Полный код ошибки

> 00000096 ServletWrappe E
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E:
>   Uncaught service() exception root cause dispatcher:
>   org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler
>   processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndViewDefiningException at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:990)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595) at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668) at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4028)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1016)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1187)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:694)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
>   at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>   at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>   at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) at
>   com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndViewDefiningException at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1028)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
>   ... 38 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndViewDefiningException at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:609) at
>   com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:243)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:924) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:869) at
>   com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:134)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:852) at
>   com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:586)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:852) at
>   com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:586)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:852) ... 40 more

Есть подозрения, что после перезагрузки classLoader читает servlet 3.0 jar файл вместо того чтобы читать servlet 3.0.1

Какое решение может быть у этой проблемы?
Понижение версии спринга до 3 версии?

Comment: А что это решает проблему?

Comment: @RomanC пока не знаю, буду пробовать онсайт через день только, хотелось бы до этого момента просто выработать стратегию решения)

Comment: Можешь добавить пробы в текст вопроса.